# Change shells in a script function

Tags: ssh, zsh, function, expect

I'm rocking ZSH as my main shell, but in my `.zshrc`, I'd like to set up a ssh command with expect so I can ssh into my dev boxes easier when I flash builds (there's literally no security needed it's all on an intranet of sorts). I can pass a password to `ssh` with `!#/usr/bin/expect` shell.

Is it kosher to do this?

```
password=sick_awesome_password6969
function expect_ssh () {
# I enter expect shell at the beginning of this function <==
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20

set cmd [lrange $argv 1 end]
set password [lindex $argv 0]

eval spawn $cmd
expect "password:"
send "$password\r";
interact
exit 0 # Then escape from it ? <==
}

default_boxssh_subnet=1
function bosh () {
    if [[ ! $1 == *"."* ]];
    then
        # ssh root@10.10.$default_boxssh_subnet.$1
        expect_ssh 10.10.$default_boxssh_subnet.$1
    else
        # ssh root@10.10.$1
        expect_ssh 10.10.$default_boxssh_subnet.$1
    fi
}
```

Comment: Shebang lines are only recognised on the first line of a script. Placed on the first line of a function, a shebang becomes a mere comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by [choroba](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592499/change-shells-in-a-script-function#comment1105180_592499), that shebang becomes a regular commentary line.

Instead having separate expect script file, you can use [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
function expect_ssh () {
expect <<'EOF'
set timeout 20

set cmd [lrange $argv 1 end]
set password [lindex $argv 0]

eval spawn $cmd
expect "password:"
send "$password\r";
interact
exit 0 # Then escape from it ? <==
EOF
}
```

Comment: Oooo, I didn't know about this! But wouldn't I still need the shebang at the beginning of the heredoc?

Comment: @WillNilges No, you don't need shebang here. It also works for other commands, not only for `expect`.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of choroba's comment, I sucked it up and wrote a helper script to call from my `.zshrc` (I also put the passwords in a file, because I figured, "Well, we're already making another file.")

Ugh, my dotfiles are going to be a mess.

**.zshrc**

```
function expect_ssh () {                                              
expect ~/.exp $2 ssh $1                                                                                                   
}                                                                     
. ~/.password_file.conf                                               
default_boxssh_subnet=1                                               
function bosh () {                                                    
    if [ -z "$2" ];                                                   
    then                                                              
        func_password=$bosh_password                                  
    else                                                              
        func_password=$2                                              
    fi                                                                
    if [[ ! $1 == *"."* ]];                                           
    then                                                              
        #ssh root@10.10.$default_boxssh_subnet.$1                     
        expect_ssh root@10.10.$default_boxssh_subnet.$1 $func_password
    else                                                              
        #ssh root@10.10.$1                                            
        expect_ssh root@10.10.$default_boxssh_subnet.$1 $func_password
    fi                                                                
}
```

**.exp**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20

set cmd [lrange $argv 1 end]
set password [lindex $argv 0]

eval spawn $cmd
expect "password:"
send "$password\r";
interact
```